# Has any high official (politician) won any medal in an important competition while holding office?

Tags: trivia, olympics, awards, participation

[This article](https://www.romaniajournal.ro/sports/cycling-romanian-minister-of-youth-and-sports-eduard-novak-wins-paralympic-silver-medal/) mentions that the current Minister of Youth and Sports won the Paralympic silver medal in Tokyo's Paralympic Games:

> Romanian cyclist Eduard Novak, the **current** Minister of Youth and
> Sports, won the Paralympic silver medal in the men’s C4 4000 m
> individual pursuit in Tokyo on Friday.

While ex-sports professionals becoming politicians is not something strange, **one holding office** that is able to compete at such a high level seems extraordinary.

I am wondering if this case is singular or not. I will provide details about the term used in the question:

- **high official** = any person being an MP or in the government
- **important competition** = any competition like Olympic Games, European (or similar for other continents) or at World level

Comment: Maybe someone can find something in here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sportsperson-politicians

Comment: I am interested in the persons actually holding office at the time of participation in the competition, not after that. Basically being a sports professional and a politician _at the same time_.

Comment: does chess count?

Comment: No, chess is not a sport for the purposes of Sports Stack Exchange. See [meta, here](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51/) for the best consensus discussion we've had of this. @Quassnoi

Comment: "any person being an MP or in the government" - I assume you mean the federal government specifically, given the term "*high* official"...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[William Grenfell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Grenfell,_1st_Baron_Desborough) competed in the 1906 [Intercalated Games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercalated_Games) in team épée. He was a UK MP until December 1905 until raised to the peerage and was - if I understand how the House of Lords worked in the early 20th century - therefore a member of the House of Lords at the time.

Answer (score 17):

Various members of the British Royal Family have won high level showjumping medals:

- [Princess Anne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anne,_Princess_Royal), the daughter of Queen Elizabeth II, won various titles including the [1971 European Eventing Championship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Eventing_Championships).
- [Mark Phillips](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Phillips), Anne's (now ex-)husband, won [an Olympic gold medal in 1972](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equestrian_at_the_1972_Summer_Olympics) (before he was married to Anne) and [a silver in 1988](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equestrian_at_the_1988_Summer_Olympics). Phillips also won a number of other equestrian titles, including four wins at the [Badminton Horse Trials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Badminton_Horse_Trials).
- [Zara Tindall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zara_Tindall), Anne and Phillips' daughter, has won a whole load of equestrian events, including [a gold medal at the 2012 Olympics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equestrian_at_the_2012_Summer_Olympics).

Comment: Princess Anne sprang to my mind too, but she's not in government.

Comment: @KenY-N The original poster clarified in (now deleted) comments that they'd consider them "on topic".

Answer (score 10):

Ukrainian [Zhan Beleniuk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zhan_Beleniuk) has been a parliamentary deputy (equivalent to MP) since 2019, and has competed at the Olympics in Greco-Roman wrestling, winning silver in 2016 and gold in 2020.  (Borderline on the timing criteria, since it was only in 2020 that he was both a medallist and politician simultaneously, although he had been both individually before 2020.)

Answer (score 10):

Russian wrestler [Alexander Karelin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleksandr_Karelin) won the World Wresting Championship in 1999 and a silver Olympic medal in 2000, while serving as a deputy to the State Duma (an MP).

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure about whether kings and royals count as politicians for the scope of the question, but several royals took part in the Olympics and some of them got a medal.

The outstanding examples are:

- King **Olaf V of Norway**, who won a gold medal sailing in the 1928 Olympic Games, when he was still the heir to the throne.
- King **Constantine II of Greece**, also gold medal sailing in the 1960 Olympic Games.

According to [this source (in Spanish)](https://www.revistavanityfair.es/realeza/galerias/miembros-de-la-realeza-que-han-ido-a-los-juegos-olimpicos-felipe-borbon-rey-juan-carlos-sofia-charlene/13251/image/757331) that seems quite comprehensive, other royals in the Olympics didn't get a medal or didn't become a monarch.

Answer (score 7):

In sailing, John Gretton (later 1st Baron Gretton) won two gold medals at the 1900 Olympic Games. Gretton served as an MP for various constituencies in the UK from 1895 until 1943 - [source](https://www.teamgb.com/athlete/john-gretton-jr/gfN9fYAW44AAnSuEKTyxw)

Answer (score 5):

I think the most famoust example is Governor Schwarzenegger winning multiple Mr. Olympia.

Manny Pacquiao is a sitting senator of the Philippines and was a champion in multiple categories in boxing

Comment: Schwarzenegger wasn't Governor when he won those titles. Pacquiao though was also a representative before he was a senator (starting in 2010). If you added titles he won since 2010, this would be a very good answer.

Answer (score 2):

The Zimbabwean born princess of Monaco, Charlene was also an Olympic swimmer for South Africa. She and her team came 5th in a relay event at the 2000 Sydney Olympics.

Comment: Ok, I just saw a poster mention princess Anne and was reminded of her. If the OP thinks this answer is bad I will consider deleting it. I will leave it for now.

Comment: In any case, if she did not win a medal, she is not countable for the question.

Answer (score 2):

British MP Edward Heath won Sydney-Hobart Yacht race while leader of the opposition and the Admirals Cup while Prime Minister.

Answer (score 1):

According to Wikipedia, the ancient Olympic Games count among their winners:

- [Philip II of Macedon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philip_II_of_Macedon) (father of Alexander the Great, on the latter's birthday no less)
- [Tiberius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiberius)
- [Nero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nero)

(However, English Wikipedia doesn't give any details on which event or even which year they won, it just lists them in their "Ancient Olympic Games" box under "Winners".)

I don't know if you count that as important. The ancient games can be argued to not be on world level, but they were definitely the most important events at the time.

Comment: Seems Nero was a winner pretty much according to himself only: https://www.thevintagenews.com/2018/08/27/nero-competed-in-the-olympics/

Comment: the sources of that box are btw listed here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ancient_Olympic_victors